# Audience video player last played video

Tags: release-freya, audience

Is there a way to make audience video player not remember the last-played video. Specifically, how to make the `current-video` attribute of audience set to a constant blank so it doesn't remember the last video you played the next time you open it. I can do that manually through `dconf-editor` but i don't want to do it every time i play a video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actually this is a feature, not a bug.**

However if you do not need it, you might want to implement some sort of solution to reset it. Some alternatives depending on your exact needs follow.

- You might want to start Audience from a wrapper script that resets
  the `org.pantheon.audience.current-video` value just after quitting:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  /usr/bin/audience
  dconf reset /org/pantheon/audience/current-video
  ```
- You might want to install a cronjob to reset it regularly:

  ```
  @hourly     dconf reset /org/pantheon/audience/current-video
  ```
- You might to want to implement a sort of watchdog that monitors it and resets it if it's not empty etc.

Comment: I didn't say it is a bug i just wanted it to be reset every time i close it. Thanks anyway!